# How to transform a function form planar symmetry to spherical symmetry?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, scattering

I'm checking some derivation in photon scattering, where there's a phrase like:

> "...transform planar symmetry to spherical symmetry...$\Psi_{sp}(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi r} \frac{d}{dr}[\varphi_{pl}(r)]$"

where the solution in planar symmetry $\varphi_{pl}(z)$ was a function of the form $B\exp(v\cdot z)$, for some constant $B$ and $v$, only with respect to $z$ axis and symmetric with respect to $z=0$.

Could you help me to understand how they did the transformation?